# Multisite maintenance1 website

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I have a multi-website (2 websites).

Now I want one of the 2 in maintenance and the other one not.

Is this possible? Or can I secure them with an htacces password for one of the 2?

Comment: https://www.demacmedia.com/mini-tutorial-improving-magento%E2%80%99s-maintenance-mode-for-store-view-specific-use/

Answer (score -1):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

adding a maintenance.flag within var of the site you want in maintenance mode will work but if you want to work on that site follow the instructions for var/.maintenance.ip to make your ip exempt

Comment: Like i said in my post i don't want maintenance on both websites. I want them on 1 of the 2.